# Installing a package on container-based Travis instance

Tags: travis-ci

I am trying to install a couple of dependency packages for testing my code on Travis-CI.  I am an education user, so all my builds get sent to a container-based instance.  Because it is container-based, I cannot use sudo to install the packages.   Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of.

Through the [`apt_packages` addon](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/apt-packages/), you can specify additional packages to be installed with your `.travis.yml` file.

```
addons:
  apt_pacakges:
    - lib32stdc++6
```

You can only installed packages that are on [the whitelist](https://github.com/travis-ci/apt-package-whitelist).